# Getting Images List using bundle

Tags: iphone

I am using this code to get the list of Images in my project

```
NSArray *pngPaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
```

I dont want to get one image from the list can i add filter to it

Thank You

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What kind of filter you want?

Comment: I think he mean he want to filter some image (maybe by name) out of the array paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is easier to do when you already load all paths into your memory NSArray. You can just loop over all elements and examine the path and remove paths you don't want